# OpenLibrary.org returns blank image, how to detect and replace them?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

For some book covers OpenLibrary.org returns a blank image ie not a 404. Example: http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/oclc/237889032-M.jpg  How, could I go about detecting and replacing these images? Would prefer to do this in the client code but willing to do it server side if needed.

Using: Meteor/React

Comment: It seems like the image is 1x1, could you detect the size of it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I haven't tested many ideas yet. I was hoping someone knew a quick easy solution. I haven't been able to google up one yet. In theory I could download the image on the server and run some image processing on it to detect size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but is not what I was looking for. I added the following to the div containing the image element. The styling should of course be moved into a css file but for simplicity I left it inline for the answer.

```
  <p className="text-center"
     style={{
              zIndex: "-1",
              position: "absolute",
              width: "40%",
              top: "10%",
              left: "30%",
             }}>
    No<br/>Cover<br/>Image<br/>Found
  </p>
```

I do not consider this a good solution as it will take a lot more manual testing to make sure there are not cases where the text is visible when it should not been. However, it is a quick and dirty solution to what seems to be a some what complex problem.

Comment: Hi! did you find any solution for the server-side?